# Webpage not working in IE9 (insertAdjacentHTML)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

IE is giving me an error (Error: Invalid target element for this operation.) when trying to execute this code:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById( name + '-body');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html );
```

Without having to put the entire function in here, the point of it is to add some text inputs dynamically when a user clicks a button.  I did a bit of searching and found many statements that insertAdjacentHTML doesn't work right within tables, which is what I need it to do.

Is there a workaround for this?

Edit: Here is the html I am trying to insert.  If you want I can post the generated html from Chrome also.

```
    "<tr id=\"node-" + counter + "\">
       <td>
         <textarea onclick=\"Common.removeInstructions(id)\" name=\"on\" id=\"action-" + counter + "\" wrap=\"soft\" cols=\"35\" rows=\"4\" style=\"resize: none; overflow: hidden;\">
        Please limit responses to 150 characters.  Blank fields will be ignored.
        </textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
  <input classname=\"TextInput\" id=\"actionDate-" + counter + "\" newline=\"1\" style=\"width: 100px;\" class=\"TextInput\" assemblers=\"jaba.ui.input.TextInput\" jaba-pagerowindex=\"1\"/>
      </td>
    </tr>"
```

Comment: If you'd show us the generated HTML and what you're trying to do, it'd be much easier to reply. Anyway, I've had a problem inserting rows/cells in a table on IE before, my solution was pre-creating the rows/cells with `display:none` when the table is created, then changing the `<td>`'s `innerHTML` together with their display. Best of luck.

Comment: I added the html that I want inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE often doesn't allow you to dynamically add table rows/cells.

Pre-creating the rows/cells which you want added with `display:none`, then changing their `innerHTML` and `display` when needed is an useful workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Fabrício Matté as an answer so I can accept it.

If you'd show us the generated HTML and what you're trying to do, it'd be much easier to reply. Anyway, I've had a problem inserting rows/cells in a table on IE before, my solution was pre-creating the rows/cells with display:none when the table is created, then changing the 's innerHTML together with their display.

Comment: I submitted it as a proper answer if you want to accept it. :P